# Prove $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n x^n$ $(x\in\mathbb{R})$ converges (Two power series, whose ratio goes to $0$ and convergence)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ $(x \in \mathbb{R})$ be a power series and $a_n$ be positive real numbers. Suppose $f(x)$ converges when $\lvert x \rvert < 1$,  and $f$ is bounded in $[0,1)$, then it is known that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n $$

converges.

Now, let $\{b_n\}$ satisfy $b_n/a_n \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$. Then, I would like to prove $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n x^n$ $(x\in\mathbb{R})$ converges on $\lvert x \rvert < 1$.

**My try:**

① For $\varepsilon = 1$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $b_n < a_n$. So,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n x^n \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n .$$

Thus, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n x^n$ is bounded. But $b_n$ is not supposed to be positive, so we should try another method.

② I tried to use ratio test, but in vain.

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{{b_n }}{{a_n }} \to 0 \Rightarrow \exists C > 0\; \forall n \ge 0:\left| {b_n } \right| \le C\left| {a_n } \right| = Ca_n .
$$ Note that you cannot prove convergence on the whole of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: But bn is not necessarily positive, and what we want to know is Σbnx^n, not Σ｜bn｜x^n. How to deal with it ?

Comment: Note that absolute convergence implies convergence. So, if you know $\sum_n |b_n|x^n$ converges, then so does $\sum_n b_n x^n$.

Comment: @Nekojiru Note that $$
\left| {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {b_n x^n } } \right| \le \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left| {b_n } \right|\left| x \right|^n } .
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $b_{n}/a_{n}\rightarrow0$, there exists $M>0$ such that $|b_{n}|\leq M|a_{n}|$
for all $n$. It is given that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ is
convergent for $|x|<1$. Hence the radius of convergence $R$ is at
least $1$. Recall that for any $x$ with $|x|<R$, the power series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ is absolutely convergent.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x|<1$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|b_{n}x^{n}| & \leq & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M|a_{n}x^{n}|\\
 & < & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}$ converges.

Comment: Perhaps you can add one more line factoring out the $M$ to the front of the power series just to make it totally clear for the OP.